# Problem saving data in firebase, I receive a: "" b: "" c: "" d: "" instead of real names

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Sometimes im receiving data in this format, which is perfectly fine:

```
   -LnIhSQcv0QGarn_1frU
    message: ""
    nameLeader: "Ken/Rubo"
    receiver: "Diego"
    receiverUid: "bustamantediego4@gmail.com"
    sender: "Ken Ramirez"
    senderUid: "kenramirezp@gmail.com"
    timestamp: 1566920004197
```

But surprisingly, sometimes I receive the data like this:

```
    -LnIk0BhKU2GS3gccabi
    a: "Diego Bustamante "
    b: "bustamantediego4@gmail.com"
    c: "kenramirezp@gmail.com"
    d: "ylx"
```

```
    "kenramirezp@gmailbcom_bustamantediego4@gmailbcom" : {
      "-Lm5nGzsAg9ey84Da3kW" : {
        "message" : "hey",
        "nameLeader" : "",
        "receiver" : "Diego Bustamante ",
        "receiverUid" : "bustamantediego4@gmail.com",
        "sender" : "Ken Ramirez",
        "senderUid" : "kenramirezp@gmail.com",
        "timestamp" : 1565629685824
      },
      "-Lm5nK9jArnIBjC0pTok" : {
        "message" : "bg",
        "nameLeader" : "",
        "receiver" : "Diego Bustamante ",
        "receiverUid" : "bustamantediego4@gmail.com",
        "sender" : "Ken Ramirez",
        "senderUid" : "kenramirezp@gmail.com",
        "timestamp" : 1565629698807
      },
      "-Lm5oTN2RTlti5-6vlPf" : {
        "message" : "habla",
        "nameLeader" : "",
        "receiver" : "Ken Ramirez ",
        "receiverUid" : "kenramirezp@gmail.com",
        "sender" : "Diego Bustamante ",
        "senderUid" : "bustamantediego4@gmail.com",
        "timestamp" : 1565629998657
      },
      "-LnIhSFL8qxGi2LrvzsH" : {
        "message" : "hrth",
        "nameLeader" : "Ken/Rubo",
        "receiver" : "Diego",
        "receiverUid" : "bustamantediego4@gmail.com",
        "sender" : "Ken Ramirez",
        "senderUid" : "kenramirezp@gmail.com",
        "timestamp" : 1566920003450
      },
      "-LnIhSGENH1G_-eR0Gj0" : {
        "message" : "hrth",
        "nameLeader" : "Ken/Rubo",
        "receiver" : "Diego",
        "receiverUid" : "bustamantediego4@gmail.com",
        "sender" : "Ken Ramirez",
        "senderUid" : "kenramirezp@gmail.com",
        "timestamp" : 1566920003728
      },
      "-LnIhSQ8Q_v6GMMz_g_u" : {
        "message" : "",
        "nameLeader" : "Ken/Rubo",
        "receiver" : "Diego",
        "receiverUid" : "bustamantediego4@gmail.com",
        "sender" : "Ken Ramirez",
        "senderUid" : "kenramirezp@gmail.com",
        "timestamp" : 1566920004013
      },
      "-LnIhSQcv0QGarn_1frU" : {
        "message" : "",
        "nameLeader" : "Ken/Rubo",
        "receiver" : "Diego",
        "receiverUid" : "bustamantediego4@gmail.com",
        "sender" : "Ken Ramirez",
        "senderUid" : "kenramirezp@gmail.com",
        "timestamp" : 1566920004197
      },
      "-LnIk0BhKU2GS3gccabi" : {
        "a" : "Diego Bustamante ",
        "b" : "bustamantediego4@gmail.com",
        "c" : "kenramirezp@gmail.com",
        "d" : "ylx"
      }
    },
```

Please help!

We have sent it without sending objects and now we are sending an object called ChatFirebase

```
ublic class Chat {
String MessageId = "", ChatId = "", UserId = "", MessageType = "", MessageData = "", ChatDate = "", FirstName = "", LastName = "", Image = "", isMine = "";

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    FirstName = firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    LastName = lastName;
}

public void setIsMine(String isMine) {
    this.isMine = isMine;
}

public String getMessageId() {
    return MessageId;
}

public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
    MessageId = messageId;
}

public String getChatId() {
    return ChatId;
}

public void setChatId(String chatId) {
    ChatId = chatId;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return UserId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    UserId = userId;
}

public String getMessageType() {
    return MessageType;
}

public void setMessageType(String messageType) {
    MessageType = messageType;
}

public String getMessageData() {
    return MessageData;
}

public void setMessageData(String messageData) {
    MessageData = messageData;
}

public String getChatDate() {
    return ChatDate;
}

public void setChatDate(String chatDate) {
    ChatDate = chatDate;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return FirstName + " " + LastName;
}

public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    Image = image;
}

public boolean isMine() {
    if (isMine.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

}

@Override
    public void sendMessageToFirebaseUser(final Context context, final ChatFirebase chat, final String receiverFirebaseToken) {
        String finalSender = chat.getSender().replace(".", "b");
        String fianlReceiver = chat.getReceiverUid().replace(".", "b");

```
    final String room_type_1 = finalSender + "_" + fianlReceiver;
    final String room_type_2 = fianlReceiver + "_" + finalSender;

    final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    databaseReference.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS).getRef().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(room_type_1)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "sendMessageToFirebaseUser: " + room_type_1 + " exists");
                databaseReference.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS).child(room_type_1).child(String.valueOf(chat.getTimestamp())).setValue(chat);
            } else if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(room_type_2)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "sendMessageToFirebaseUser: " + room_type_2 + " exists");
                databaseReference.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS).child(room_type_2).child(String.valueOf(chat.getTimestamp())).setValue(chat);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "sendMessageToFirebaseUser: success");
                databaseReference.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS).child(room_type_1).child(String.valueOf(chat.getTimestamp())).setValue(chat);
                getMessageFromFirebaseUser(chat.getSenderUid(), chat.getReceiverUid());
            }
            // send push notification to the receiver
            //sendNotification(chat.getReceiverUid(), chat.getMessage(), chat.getSender(), chat.getSenderUid(), new SharedPrefUtil(context).getString(Constants.ARG_FIREBASE_TOKEN));
            mOnSendMessageListener.onSendMessageSuccess();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            mOnSendMessageListener.onSendMessageFailure("Unable to send message: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

I expect Firebase to receive the data in the same format everytime.

Json file url [JSON FILE](https://gofile.io/?c=opAME6)

Comment: Just check your code Somewhere you must be sending the data in the second format or just check your firebase database, there might be some data of the wrong format

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I just added the requested file. Thanks for your help Alex!

Comment: We don't need the entire JSON file, just add a sample of it to your question or at least a screenshot of it.

Comment: @AlexMamo   "gianboy1@gmailbcom" : {
      "chats" : {
        "kenramirezp@gmailbcom" : {
          "message" : "oh",
          "nameLeader" : "",
          "receiver" : "Rod",
          "receiverUid" : "kp@gm.com",
          "sender" : "Gian R",
          "senderUid" : "gian@gmail.com",
          "timestamp" : 156974306
        }
      }
    },
    "kenramirezp@gmailbcom" : {
      "chats" : {
        "bust@gmailbcom" : {
          "a" : "Diego mante ",
          "b" : "busdiego4@gmail.com",
          "c" : "kenra@gmail.com",
          "d" : "ylx"
        },

Comment: Please add it to your question not as comment.

Comment: How is the `chat` object defined? Show us all the code that is related to adding data to the database.

Comment: @AlexMamo i just added it

Comment: Have you found the issue?